# Is this method of importing modules, in Python, causing a loop?

Tags: python, module, import

app/__ init__.py

```
from blah import test
```

app/x.py

```
from app import *

test()
```

Basically, I have an `__init__.py` file that contains a bunch of imports that will be used throughout the app. I've put them all in here to save me having to import them into each file (every file within this folder will use the same imports)

I'm wondering if that `from app import *` line is causing it to import itself as it is inside the `app` folder...

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Subpackages and modules within a package are never imported when the package is imported unless they are explicitly imported within `__init__.py`. Even if they *were*, the most that would happen is that the module would contain a reference to itself, which is not considered a problem.